# Convert HttpServletResponse to json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have the following ExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ValueNotAllowedException.class)
void handleBadRequests(HttpServletResponse response, ValueNotAllowedException ex) throws IOException {
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), ex.getMessage());
}
```

Response's type is `HTML`. 
[image]
How to easily convert response into smth like that:

(response from another controller in project. My response should be similar)

```
{
  "timestamp": 1476462787425,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Start date should be before or equal end date\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@47842b65; line: 23, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.instinctools.mailtracker.endpoints.dto.QueryFilterDTO[\"startDate\"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Start date should be before or equal end date\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@47842b65; line: 23, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.instinctools.mailtracker.endpoints.dto.QueryFilterDTO[\"startDate\"])",
  "path": "/statistics/clicks"
}
```

Comment: This is obvious, isn't it ? URL parameter startDate > endDate.

Comment: @PeterMmm you didn't understand. I write backend on java. In whole project when exception occurs its response is json info about it (see example in topic). But my ExceptionHandler (it was written for my controller) has wrong style of exception (HTML page). How I can convert `response` data to json? I do not understand exactly how other controllers generate such json info, maybe it is standard spring-boot option?

Answer (score 2):

Create a base `Error` object (annotated properly), which is returned to the `UI`.

```
class Error {
  private String timestamp;
  private Integer status;
  private String error;
  private String exception;
  private String message;
  private String path;

  //constructors here, whatever
 .....
}
```

..then change your ExceptionHandler with something like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(ValueNotAllowedException.class)
@ResponseBody Error handleBadRequest(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    //Create and return your Error object here. 
    return new Error(/* populate with all the stuff you need here */);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ty, I understand your approach. But it isn't exactly what I need. I suppose, there are native (in spring-boot) way to generate such json, because I don't see in project smth like that Error class... What do you think?

Comment: You create the Error class yourself. You can name it anything really. So, just create a class, your model for an Error right. Then, you populate that object with status, message, exception information, etc.. and send it to the UI. Note the @ResponseBody annotation and how the return type is the Error object itself.

Comment: The Error class, gets translated to a JSON object internally. From the UI aspect, if you request JSON back from your backend, Spring will translate the Error to a JSON.

Comment: did u understand that in project there are a lot of controllers and they send json info about exceptions without any Error class. Just throw new Exception("Bla-bla"); and it works (I don't know how, I am new at spring). But in my controller it doesn't work and I wrote ExceptionHandler for my exception class. Last step - set up it right...

Comment: No, you didnot give all that information in your question. The approach i am giving is Spring-recommended: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc